# Android: Load text file located in app/src/main/

Tags: android, text-files

I'm attempting to use some code to load a basic changelog from a text file into an alert dialog. The only issue is that I am having trouble getting my code to find the location of my changelog file. The file "changelog" is located in app/src/main/. Here is a sample of my code.

```
private void displayChangelogDialog() {
    Context context = this;
    try {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Changelog")
                .setMessage(readFile(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/app/src/main/changelog"))
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am not very familiar with getFilesDir() or getAbsolutePath(), so I'd imagine this would be a good learning experience if anyone can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm sure the problem resides in the path I have entered, but I am a bit stumped at the moment. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`getFilesDir` documentation:

Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with `openFileOutput(String, int)` are stored.

Typically, `openFileOutput` access to `/data/data`, which is completly different from your application install path.
If you want to access a file, put it in the `assets` folder the check the assets related functions (see [`AssetManaget`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html))